# Symfony 1.4 Propel - duplicate declarations for same class - sfAutoload error?

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I get this error why I try to sort the results from a basic admin-generated list on backend:

Never had this problem again:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class BasePhotoPeer in
>   PROJECTNAME\lib\model\om\BasePhotoPeer.php on line 10 Call
>   Stack
>   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0004  370000  {main}( )   ..\backend_dev.php:0 2  0.1291  6509976 sfContext->dispatch(
>   ) ..\backend_dev.php:13
>   3 0.1291  6510008 sfFrontWebController->dispatch(
>   ) ..\sfContext.class.php:170 4    0.1296  6529528 sfController->forward(
>   ) ..\sfFrontWebController.class.php:48
>   5 0.1494  7268288 sfFilterChain->execute(
>   ) ..\sfController.class.php:238
>   6 0.1497  7269144 sfRenderingFilter->execute(
>   ) ..\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
>   7 0.1497  7269144 sfFilterChain->execute(
>   ) ..\sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33
>   8 0.1499  7269976 sfBasicSecurityFilter->execute(
>   ) ..\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
>   9 0.1500  7270008 sfFilterChain->execute(
>   ) ..\sfBasicSecurityFilter.class.php:72
>   10    0.1502  7270960 sfExecutionFilter->execute(
>   ) ..\sfFilterChain.class.php:53
>   11    0.1503  7271704 sfExecutionFilter->handleAction(
>   ) ..\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:42
>   12    0.1503  7271704 sfExecutionFilter->executeAction(
>   ) ..\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:78
>   13    0.1537  7377448 sfActions->execute(
>   ) ..\sfExecutionFilter.class.php:92
>   14    0.1539  7378328 autoPhotoActions->executeIndex(
>   ) ..\sfActions.class.php:60
>   15    0.1626  8232616 autoPhotoActions->getPager(
>   ) ..\actions.class.php:45
>   16    0.1627  8232664 sfModelGeneratorConfiguration->getPager(
>   ) ..\actions.class.php:129
>   17    0.1645  8382080 sfPropelPager->__construct(
>   ) ..\sfModelGeneratorConfiguration.class.php:469
>   18    0.1721  9275456 constant ( )    ..\sfPropelPager.class.php:37
>   19    0.1722  9275688 sfAutoload->autoload( ) ..\sfPropelPager.class.php:0
>   20    0.1722  9275688 sfAutoload->loadClass( )    ..\sfAutoload.class.php:163
>   21    0.1725  9295720 require(
>   'PROJECTNAME\lib\model\PhotoPeer.php'
>   ) ..\sfAutoload.class.php:188 22  0.1742  9556976 require(
>   'PROJECTNAME\lib\model\om\BasePhotoPeer.php'
>   ) ..\PhotoPeer.php:3

This happens to all the models on which I generated a backend admin module. One temporary solution is to remove the line `require 'lib/model/om/BaseENTITYPeer.php';` from the `ENTITYPeer.php class`.

But I can't understand why this line is here from the first place (all the models where generated classic using propel). On the other projects I made there were no line like this appearing on the entity classes.

Comment: Have you tried to generated model classes?

Comment: @j0k - Of course. cleared the OM and MAP folders. regenerated the classes. Cleared the cache.. tried everything

Comment: do try to find BasePhotoPeer string all around your project, i had similar problems due to duplicate classes in diferent paths..